# Checking if a specific date is closed in a JSON data stored within a text field in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, stored-procedures, json

## Problem Description

I'm currently working on a complex stored procedure that involves a table called "price_options_test". Within this table, there is a text field named "close_days" that stores closed days in JSON format. I need assistance with implementing a query that can determine if a specific date is a closed day.

For instance, if I provide the date "2023-06-21" as input to the query, I would like it to convert the date to the corresponding day name (e.g., "wednesday"). Subsequently, the query should check the "close_days" field to determine if the day is closed e.g. "wednesday": true. If the day is closed, the query should return true or 1; otherwise, it should return false or 0.

### Test Case:

- Date: "2023-06-21"
- ID: 1
- "close_days" JSON value: {"monday": false, "tuesday": false,
  "wednesday": true, "thursday": false, "friday": false, "saturday":
  false, "sunday": false}

> The expected result is that the query should return true. This is
> because the provided date corresponds to "wednesday," and in the JSON
> object, the value for "wednesday" is true.

### What I'm trying

Following condition is not working:

```
JSON_EXTRACT(close_days, CONCAT('$.', DATE_FORMAT(startDate, '%W'))) IS NULL OR JSON_EXTRACT(close_days, CONCAT('$.', DATE_FORMAT(startDate, '%W'))) = false)
```

## Required Output

I want **true** or **false** based on date.

---

### MariaDB Query & Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE `price_options_test` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `slots` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_days` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_slots` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `price_options_test` (`id`, `slots`, `close_days`, `quantity`, `list_slots`) VALUES
(1, 1, '{"monday": false, "tuesday": false, "wednesday": true, "thursday": false, "friday": false, "saturday": false, "sunday": false}', 0, '[{"start": "09:00", "quantity": 30}, {"start": "09:30", "quantity": 30}]'),
(2, 0, '{"monday": false, "tuesday": false, "wednesday": true, "thursday": false, "friday": false, "saturday": false, "sunday": false}', 30, NULL);
```

### Important Note

- 1- close_days field type is text, so JSON functions may not apply.
  directly.
- The MariaDB version I'm using is 10.4.24-MariaDB (Xampp).

---

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or examples on how to accomplish this task efficiently within a stored procedure. Thank you!

Comment: Please be aware that MySQL and MariaDB are different products. In particular, they have independent implementations of JSON features, since they both developed JSON support after MariaDB forked from MySQL. I have edited your title and tags to clarify that you are using MariaDB, not MySQL.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot Bill

Answer (score 0):

> Test Case:
>
> Date: "2023-06-21"
>
> ID: 1
>
> The expected result is that the query should return true.

```
SET @date := '2023-06-21', @id := 1;
```

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(close_days, CONCAT('$.', LOWER(DAYNAME(@date))))
FROM price_options_test
WHERE id = @id;
```

| JSON_EXTRACT(close_days, CONCAT('$.', LOWER(DAYNAME(@date)))) |
| --- |
| true |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xgR4IMkE)